# How Magento Commerce Support Flash Sale

Tags: sales, magento-2-commerce

I am using community edition, recently know commerce edition has the feature like Flash Sale, what are all the options available any docs related to this please welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Magento 2 Flash sale Extension is useful for you.
Link: https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-flash-sale.html
Documentation: http://guide.landofcoder.com/lof-flash-sale-user-guide/

They also provide support via email, technical support (ticket) and forum. YOu can get a quick support as well.

Thanks